# Draw many circles on canvas vs create a custom Container for them

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

I'm new in flutter, and I need to visualize somehow many huge pixels in my application and refresh their color in every 150ms.

The pixels will be in a matrix form and their count can be more than 1000.

What can be the most effective way to visualize them?

For such amount elements, should i still stick to creating a custom StatelessWidget or try to draw them on a canvas?
Also I've noticed, using animations would rebuild the whole pixel matrix, what is also really not efficient, can you advise how should I do the refreshes?

Thanks

Comment: It will be much more performant to draw them manually on the canvas (RenderObject/CustomPainter).

Comment: Can you be more specific about the use case and the animations? Is it just a fixed animation, or something you can interact with?

Comment: It's only a fixed animation.